# Spring boot project crashes if I add any values to application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am simply trying to add environment variables to my project. No matter what I add to my `application.properties` file, the program crashes and the `pom.xml` suddenly becomes invalid and highlighted red in my IDE.
For example: If I add this to my `application.properties` file:

```
my.test="hello"
```

Then the `pom.xml` file becomes highlighted red with errors in my IDE and the program fails to start.

This is the error from within my pom file:

```
Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources failed: newPosition < 0: (-1 < 0) (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources:default-resources:process-resources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources failed: newPosition < 0: (-1 < 0)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.lambda$8(MavenImpl.java:1423)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1422)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$1(MavenBuilder.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$0(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: newPosition < 0: (-1 < 0)
    at java.base/java.nio.Buffer.createPositionException(Buffer.java:318)
    at java.base/java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:293)
    at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.position(ByteBuffer.java:1086)
    at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.position(ByteBuffer.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1946)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile(DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources(DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute(ResourcesMojo.java:356)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    ... 30 more
```

[image: highlighted red]

Comment: Plase show full pom file? Which Maven version do you use? Which JDK Version do you use? etc. How do you call Maven? Do you run on plain command line?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65673111/illegalargumentexception-in-maven-resources-plugin-during-deploy-goal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have problem with encoding. Try add to your pom next property:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Comment: I was still having this issue with the proper encoding. Solved it by doing a `mvn clean`.