# How to run spring boot application with profile from commandline?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am using spring boot and maven to have multiple environments for dev, unit test, integration test, stage, and prod environment.

Test: with `@Profile`

```
@SpringBootTest
@Profile("utest")
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

I have tried with `@ActiveProfiles` too. It does not work.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("utest")
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Folder structure:

```
.
├── java
│   └── com
│       └── example
│           └── demo
│               └── DemoApplication.java
└── resources
    ├── application-utest.properties
    ├── application.properties
    ├── static
    └── templates
```

I have created a new file `application-utest.properties` file.

application.properties

```
server.port=5001
```

application-utest.properties

```
server.port=6000
```

When I run:
`mvn test -P utest`

Getting this error:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< com.example:demo >--------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ demo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.779 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-15T23:00:38+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "utest" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) on project demo: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources failed: newPosition < 0: (-1 < 0) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

This says the profile does not exist. How to use spring boot profiles the correct way?

Comment: Spring boot profiles are something different than maven profiles. You don't need to activate the spring boot profiles via command line because you have defined that in your tests already...

Comment: Apart from a general recommendation never having some configuration in your application. Better giving that in the run environment later not during built time...

Comment: I will pass all the values from environment, but I need some placeholder in these application properties files during different stages in ci/cd

Comment: have a look here: [baeldung spring-profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

Comment: It seems you are facing [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69844566/525036) which is unrelated to Spring profiles. OTOH, you should probably not use Spring for unit tests since they should test classes in isolation. `@ActiveProfiles("utest")` should work for integration tests without command-line parameters. For the rest it will depend how you run your application.

Comment: I am assuming that you are having "application-utest.properties" file under "src/main/resources" folder. Can you move "application-utest.properties" file to "src/test/resources" and try again?